# Is it possible to add custom context to the .zfproject.xml?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to add custom context `classesDirectory` in `applicationDirectory` section to the `.zfproject.xml`.

I have created a context class, that extends `Zend_Tool_Project_Context_Filesystem_Directory` but the issue is that all contexts loading necessary to parse `.zfproject.xml` are hardcoded in `Zend_Tool_Project_Provider_Abstract` class as:

```
$contextRegistry->addContextsFromDirectory(
    dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Context/Zf/', 'Zend_Tool_Project_Context_Zf_'
);
$contextRegistry->addContextsFromDirectory(
    dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Context/Filesystem/', 'Zend_Tool_Project_Context_Filesystem_'
);
```

So I don't see any way to load my context without patching zend sources (or adding custom files to Zend library directories).

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible without changing the ZF source code. You could try creating an issue on http://framework.zend.com/issues along with a patch. Please make this generic though.

Alternatively, what are you trying to do that requires a custom context? Maybe there's another way to solve it?

Comment: I introduce another sort of entities that should be stored in another directory within application. Say `application/foo` directory and `application/foo/bar.php` file. For that I created new contexts and successfully generate them, but got in stuck on step of saving/parsing new contexts into `.zfproject.xml`

Comment: I see. I think you'll need to change the ZF source code for that. Another alternative may be to create your own XML file with the project root such as`.zfcustom.xml` and use that from your provider.